# How can I use @ImportResource to import an entire directory of config files in src/main/resources/static?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Just like the title says, how can I use the `@ImportResource` annotation to import config files in src/main/resources/static directory? When I try accessing it like this:

`@ImportResource("/nameOfDirectory/*.xml)`

I get an error saying the URL doesn't exist.

Comment: Not sure if it will work for an entire directory, but your path must be a valid url, in your case something like `file:///the/path/to/my/project/file.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a SpringBoot app? If so, files in the src/main/resources/static is meant for web resources (templates, css, js, images) in a SpringMVC app.

Recommend to move them to a different folder (or keep them in src/main/resources. Per the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html), ant-style regex patterns to get the files you need works fine.